# Is there a Unix utility to prepend timestamps to stdin?

Tags: unix, shell, awk

I ended up writing a quick little script for this in Python, but I was wondering if there was a utility you could feed text into which would prepend each line with some text -- in my specific case, a timestamp.  Ideally, the use would be something like:

```
cat somefile.txt | prepend-timestamp
```

(Before you answer sed, I tried this:

```
cat somefile.txt | sed "s/^/`date`/"
```

But that only evaluates the date command once when sed is executed, so the same timestamp is incorrectly prepended to each line.)

Comment: Is the `cat somefile.txt` a bit "misleading"? I'd expect it to happen "at once" and have a single timestamp. Wouldn't this be a better test program: `(echo a; sleep 1; echo b; sleep 3; echo c; sleep 2)`?

Comment: looks like none of the answers will easily give me milliseconds (I'm on Mac)

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Could try using `awk`:

```
<command> | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'
```

You may need to make sure that `<command>` produces line buffered output, i.e. it flushes its output stream after each line; the timestamp `awk` adds will be the time that the end of the line appeared on its input pipe.

If awk shows errors, then try `gawk` instead.

Comment: On my system 'awk' itself was buffering. (This can be problematic for log files). I fixed this by using:

    awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'

Comment: strftime() appears to be a GNU awk extension, so if you're on Mac OS, for example, use gawk instead of awk.

Comment: It doesn't cease to amaze me how powerful bash is. I didn't think there would be such an easy solution for this complicated task.

Comment: For OS X users, you have to install `gawk` and use that instead of `awk`. If you have MacPorts: `sudo port install gawk`

Comment: Is there any way to add milliseconds to the timestamp?

Comment: @teh_senaus As far as I know, `awk`'s `strftime()` does not have millisecond precision. However you can use the `date` command. Basically you just trim nanoseconds to three characters. It will look like this: `COMMAND | while read -r line; do echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %T.%3N') $line"; done`. Note that you can abbreviate %H:%M:%S with %T. If you still want to use `awk` for some reason, you can do the following: `COMMAND | awk '{ "date +%Y-%m-%d\\ %T.%3N" | getline timestamp; print timestamp, $0; fflush(); }'`

Comment: `awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"), $0; fflush(); }'` prints out the ISO8601 format, just in case you need it.

Comment: It doesn't print the time for each line when it appeared: `ruby -e "puts 1; sleep 1; puts 2; sleep 2; puts 3" | gawk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'`

Comment: @Turtle it will if you "apt-get install gawk". Raspbian includes mawk (without strftime support) by default but you can just replace it with gawk.

Comment: if you use gawk's extension library, then yes even nanosecond is available : echo "abc 123 xyz\njan 765 feb" | gawk -be '@load"time"; BEGIN {_=sprintf("%.9f ",gettimeofday()) } sub("^", _)'
1649525790.805718899 abc 123 xyz
1649525790.805718899 jan 765 feb

Answer (score 208):

`ts` from [moreutils](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/) will prepend a timestamp to every line of input you give it. You can format it using strftime too.

```
$ echo 'foo bar baz' | ts
Mar 21 18:07:28 foo bar baz
$ echo 'blah blah blah' | ts '%F %T'
2012-03-21 18:07:30 blah blah blah
$
```

To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install moreutils
```

Comment: to capture and stamp stderr at the same time: `bad command 2>&1 | ts` results in `Jan 29 19:58:31 -bash: bad: command not found`

Comment: I want to use the time format `2014 Mar 21 18:07:28`. How do I get it?

Comment: @becko - according to the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ts), give a `strftime` format string as argument: `[.. command ..] | ts '%Y %b %d %T'`, for example.

Comment: For OS X, `brew install moreutils`. To output UTC, you can set TZ locally, e.g. `ls -l |TZ=UTC ts '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'`

Comment: It doesn't print the time for each line when it appeared `ruby -e "puts 1; sleep 1; puts 2; sleep 2; puts 3" | ts '%F %T'`

Comment: @Dorian this is because ruby is buffering the output; if you flush the buffer before sleeping it works well enough: `ruby -e "puts 1; STDOUT.flush; sleep 1; puts 2; STDOUT.flush; sleep 2; puts 3" | ts '%F %T'`

Comment: I thought `ts` must be some super tiny binary so this is somehow *leaner* than using `(g)awk` for this only to find out it's a Perl script… What a pity.

Comment: For those that want an epoch, let me save you the time of looking it up: `ts '%s'`

Answer (score 48):

[annotate](http://jeroen.a-eskwadraat.nl/sw/annotate/annotate), available via that link or as `annotate-output` in the Debian `devscripts` package.

```
$ echo -e "a\nb\nc" > lines
$ annotate-output cat lines
17:00:47 I: Started cat lines
17:00:47 O: a
17:00:47 O: b
17:00:47 O: c
17:00:47 I: Finished with exitcode 0
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but will not work with piped output or subshelled output. It will only reformat the output for a program or script that you give it as an argument.

Comment: annotate-output works nicely and is easy to use, but is REALLY slow.

Answer (score 31):

Distilling the given answers to the simplest one possible:

```
unbuffer $COMMAND | ts
```

On Ubuntu, they come from the expect-dev and moreutils packages.

```
sudo apt-get install expect-dev moreutils
```

Comment: It's `expect`, not `expect-dev`, but the latter pulls in the former so this works.  (Ubuntu 14.10, I wonder if the binary was moved to a different package at some point.)

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, it's still in ```expect-dev```

Comment: If you'd like to get elapsed time with millisecond accuracy, use `unbuffer $COMMAND | ts -s %.s` (`-s` if for elapsed time and `%.s` for time in seconds with fractional part)

Answer (score 26):

How about this?

```
cat somefile.txt | perl -pne 'print scalar(localtime()), " ";'
```

Judging from your desire to get live timestamps, maybe you want to do live updating on a log file or something?  Maybe

```
tail -f /path/to/log | perl -pne 'print scalar(localtime()), " ";' > /path/to/log-with-timestamps
```

Comment: This perl example was particularly useful for me as I was working as a user on an ubuntu deployment, which apparently uses 'mawk' instead of 'gawk' -- and doesn't have the strftime function.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 to this being handy on a default Ubuntu install. I used `tail -f /path/to/log | perl -pne 'use POSIX qw(strftime); print strftime "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ ", gmtime();'` to get an ISO8601/RFC3339 style date instead of the wacko one the simpler version yields.

Comment: If you want to be able look at timestamped log output as it arrives, it may be helpful to add `BEGIN { $|++; }` before the print statement in order to have Perl flush its output with each line.

Comment: You can shorten the perl script further to just `ls | perl -pne 'print localtime." "'`. The scalar conversion happens due to string concatenation.

Comment: Why do you use both `-p` and `-n` options? It seems like `-n` is redundant if you have specified `-p`.

Answer (score 19):

Kieron's answer is the best one so far.  If you have problems because the first program is buffering its out you can use the unbuffer program:

```
unbuffer <command> | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }'
```

It's installed by default on most linux systems.  If you need to build it yourself it is part of the expect package

http://expect.nist.gov

Comment: Note that I've found that 'unbuffer' sometimes hides the return result of the called program - so it's not useful in Jenkins or other things that rely on the return status

Answer (score 19):

Just gonna throw this out there: there are a pair of utilities in [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) called [tai64n](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/tai64n.html) and [tai64nlocal](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/tai64nlocal.html) that are made for prepending timestamps to log messages.

Example:

```
cat file | tai64n | tai64nlocal
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the read(1) command to read one line at a time from standard input, then output the line prepended with the date in the format of your choosing using date(1).

```
$ cat timestamp
#!/bin/sh
while read line
do
  echo `date` $line
done
$ cat somefile.txt | ./timestamp
```

Comment: A bit heavyweight as it forks a new process per line, but it works!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an Unix guy, but I think you can use

```
gawk '{print strftime("%d/%m/%y",systime()) $0 }' < somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#! /bin/sh
unbuffer "$@" | perl -e '
use Time::HiRes (gettimeofday);
while(<>) {
        ($s,$ms) = gettimeofday();
        print $s . "." . $ms . " " . $_;
}'
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> $ cat somefile.txt | sed "s/^/`date`/"
> ```

you can do this (with *gnu/sed*):

```
$ some-command | sed "x;s/.*/date +%T/e;G;s/\n/ /g"
```

example:

```
$ { echo 'line1'; sleep 2; echo 'line2'; } | sed "x;s/.*/date +%T/e;G;s/\n/ /g"
20:24:22 line1
20:24:24 line2
```

of course, you can use other options of the program *date*. just replace `date +%T` with what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my awk solution (from a Windows/XP system with MKS Tools installed in the C:\bin directory). It is designed to add the current date and time in the form mm/dd hh:mm to the beginning of each line having fetched that timestamp from the system as each line is read.  You could, of course, use the BEGIN pattern to fetch the timestamp once and add that timestamp to each record (all the same).  I did this to tag a log file that was being generated to stdout with the timestamp at the time the log message was generated.

`/"pattern"/      "C\:\\\\bin\\\\date '+%m/%d %R'" | getline timestamp;`
`print timestamp, $0;`

where "pattern" is a string or regex (without the quotes) to be matched in the input line, and is optional if you wish to match all input lines.

This should work on Linux/UNIX systems as well, just get rid of the C\:\\bin\\ leaving the line

```
             "date '+%m/%d %R'" | getline timestamp;
```

This, of course, assumes that the command "date" gets you to the standard Linux/UNIX date display/set command without specific path information (that is, your environment PATH variable is correctly configured).

Comment: On OS X I needed a space before the date command.  Sadly it doesn't seem to re-evaluate the command for each line.  Like others have suggested, I'm trying to add timestamps to tail -f.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing some answers above from [natevw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179583/natevw) and Frank Ch. Eigler.

It has milliseconds, performs better than calling a external `date` command each time and perl can be found in most of the servers.

```
tail -f log | perl -pne '
  use Time::HiRes (gettimeofday);
  use POSIX qw(strftime);
  ($s,$ms) = gettimeofday();
  print strftime "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+$ms ", gmtime($s);
  '
```

Alternative version with flush and read in a loop:

```
tail -f log | perl -pne '
  use Time::HiRes (gettimeofday); use POSIX qw(strftime);
  $|=1;
  while(<>) {
    ($s,$ms) = gettimeofday();
    print strftime "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+$ms $_", gmtime($s);
  }'
```

Comment: Two flaws with the above:
1. $ms is not aligned and zero-padded.
2. Any % codes in the log will be mangled.

Thus instead of the print line, I used:

`printf "%s+%06d %s", (strftime "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", gmtime($s)), $ms, $_;`

Answer (score 1):

caerwyn's answer can be run as a subroutine, which would prevent the new processes per line:

```
timestamp(){
   while read line
      do
         echo `date` $line
      done
}

echo testing 123 |timestamp
```

Comment: how does that prevent `date` from being spawned at every line ?

Comment: @Gyom It doesn't prevent date to be spawned every line. It prevents **shell** from spawning every line.

I would add that in bash you coud do something like: `timestamp() { while read line; do echo "$(date) $line"; done; }; export -f timestamp` in a script that you source.

Comment: Calling date as a subprocess still means spawning it for every line, however you launch the script in the first place.

Comment: To prevent spawning command `date` for every line, try using bash `printf` builtin with **%(datespec)T** format. So it may look like `timestamp() { while IFS= read -r line; do printf "%(%F %T)T %s\n" -1 "$line"; done; }`. Shell builtins won't spawn.
Datespec format is like `strftime(3)` i.e. `date` formats. This requires bash, not sure since which version it supports that `printf` specifier.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: the solution I am proposing is not a Unix built-in utility.

I faced a similar problem a few days ago. I did not like the syntax and limitations of the solutions above, so I quickly put together a program in Go to do the job for me.

You can check the tool here: **[preftime](https://github.com/mokiat/preftime)**

There are prebuilt executables for Linux, MacOS, and Windows in the [Releases](https://github.com/mokiat/preftime/releases) section of the GitHub project.

The tool handles incomplete output lines and has (from my point of view) a more compact syntax.

`<command> | preftime`

It's not ideal, but I though I'd share it in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers mostly work, but have some drawbacks. In particular:

1. Many require installing a command not commonly found on linux systems, which may not be possible or convenient.
2. Since they use pipes, they don't put timestamps on stderr, and lose the exit status.
3. If you use multiple pipes for stderr and stdout, then some do not have atomic printing, leading to intermingled lines of output like `[timestamp] [timestamp] stdout line \nstderr line`
4. Buffering can cause problems, and `unbuffer` requires an extra dependency.

To solve (4), we can use `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0` which is generally available on most linux systems (see [How to make output of any shell command unbuffered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered)).

To solve (3), you just need to be careful to print the entire line at a time.

- Bad: `ruby -pe 'print Time.now.strftime(\"[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] \")'` (Prints the timestamp, then prints the contents of `$_`.)
- Good: `ruby -pe '\$_ = Time.now.strftime(\"[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] \") + \$_'` (Alters `$_`, then prints it.)

To solve (2), we need to use multiple pipes and save the exit status:

```sh
alias tslines-pipe="stdbuf -i0 -o0 ruby -pe '\$_ = Time.now.strftime(\"[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] \") + \$_'"
function tslines() (
  stdbuf -o0 -e0 "$@" 2> >(tslines-pipe) > >(tslines-pipe)
  status="$?"
  exit $status
)
```

Then you can run a command with `tslines some command --options`.

This *almost* works, except sometimes one of the pipes takes slightly longer to exit and the `tslines` function has exited, so the next prompt has printed. For example, this command seems to print all the output after the prompt for the next line has appeared, which can be a bit confusing:

```
tslines bash -c '(for (( i=1; i<=20; i++ )); do echo stderr 1>&2; echo stdout;  done)'
```

There needs to be some coordination method between the two pipe processes and the tslines function. There are presumably many ways to do this. One way I found is to have the pipes send some lines to a pipe that the main function can listen to, and only exit *after* it's received data from both pipe handlers. Putting that together:

```sh
alias tslines-pipe="stdbuf -i0 -o0 ruby -pe '\$_ = Time.now.strftime(\"[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] \") + \$_'"
function tslines() (
  # Pick a random name for the pipe to prevent collisions.
  pipe="/tmp/pipe-$RANDOM"
  
  # Ensure the pipe gets deleted when the method exits.
  trap "rm -f $pipe" EXIT

  # Create the pipe.  See https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash
  mkfifo "$pipe"
  # echo will block until the pipe is read.
  stdbuf -o0 -e0 "$@" 2> >(tslines-pipe; echo "done" >> $pipe) > >(tslines-pipe; echo "done" >> $pipe)
  status="$?"

  # Wait until we've received data from both pipe commands before exiting.
  linecount=0
  while [[ $linecount -lt 2 ]]; do
    read line
    if [[ "$line" == "done" ]]; then
      ((linecount++))
    fi
  done < "$pipe"
  exit $status
)
```

That synchronization mechanism feels a bit convoluted; hopefully there's a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

doing it with `date` and `tr` and `xargs` on OSX:

```
alias predate="xargs -I{} sh -c 'date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\" | tr \"\n\" \" \"; echo \"{}\"'"
<command> | predate
```

if you want milliseconds:

```
alias predate="xargs -I{} sh -c 'date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N\" | tr \"\n\" \" \"; echo \"{}\"'"
```

but note that on OSX, date doesn't give you the %N option, so you'll need to install gdate (`brew install coreutils`) and so finally arrive at this:

```
alias predate="xargs -I{} sh -c 'gdate +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N\" | tr \"\n\" \" \"; echo \"{}\"'"
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to specify all the parameters in `strftime()` unless you really want to customize the outputting format :

```
   echo "abc 123 xyz\njan 765 feb" \
    \
    | gawk -Sbe 'BEGIN {_=strftime()" "} sub("^",_)'

    Sat Apr  9 13:14:53 EDT 2022 abc 123 xyz
    Sat Apr  9 13:14:53 EDT 2022 jan 765 feb
```

works the same if you have `mawk 1.3.4.` Even on `awk`-variants without the time features, a quick getline could emulate it :

```
echo "abc 123 xyz\njan 765 feb" \
\
| mawk2 'BEGIN {     (__="date")|getline _;
                close(__)
                        _=_" " } sub("^",_)'
   
Sat Apr  9 13:19:38 EDT 2022 abc 123 xyz
Sat Apr  9 13:19:38 EDT 2022 jan 765 feb
```

If you wanna skip all that getline and BEGIN { }, then something like this :

```
mawk2 'sub("^",_" ")' \_="$(date)"
```

Answer (score -1):

If the value you are prepending is the same on every line, fire up emacs with the file, then:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd><space></kbd>

at the beginning of the of the file (to mark that spot), then scroll down to the beginning of the last line (Alt + > will go to the end of file... which probably will involve the Shift key too, then Ctrl + a to go to the beginning of that line) and:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd>

Which is the command to insert at the rectangle you just specified (a rectangle of 0 width).

2008-8-21 6:45PM <enter>

Or whatever you want to prepend... then you will see that text prepended to every line within the 0 width rectangle.

UPDATE: I just realized you don't want the SAME date, so this won't work... though you may be able to do this in emacs with a slightly more complicated custom macro, but still, this kind of rectangle editing is pretty nice to know about...