# How to make output (stdout, stderr) of any shell command unbuffered?

Tags: stdout, buffering

Is there a way to run shell commands without output buffering?

For example, `hexdump file | ./my_script` will only pass input from hexdump to my_script in buffered chunks, not line by line.

What is a general solution to make the output for any command unbuffered?

Comment: more upvoted question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161821/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream

Answer (score 25, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't do it without ugly hacks. Writing to a pipe (or reading from it) automatically turns on full buffering and there is nothing you can do about it :-(. "Line buffering" (which is what you want) is only used when reading/writing a terminal. The ugly hacks exactly do this: They connect a program to a pseudo-terminal, so that the other tools in the pipe read/write from that terminal in line buffering mode. The whole problem is described here:

- http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

The page has also some suggestions (the aforementioned "ugly hacks") what to do, i.e. using `unbuffer` or pulling some tricks with `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: Thanks. I had never heard about pseudo terminals before.

Answer (score 175):

Try `stdbuf`, included in GNU coreutils and thus virtually any Linux distro.  This sets the buffer length for input, output and error to zero:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 command
```

Comment: This worked better than `unbuffer` for me. `stdbuf` passed any signals (`SIGUSR2` in my case) I sent to it to the `command` (which is what I wanted to happen), while `unbuffer` didn't seem to want to.

Comment: stdbuf uses one the aforementioned LD_PRELOAD tricks to do this and hence does not work with statically linked or setuid executables. See this question for a discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644024/stdbuf-with-setuid-capabilities/18624182#18624182

Comment: I found this very useful, but limited, as it does not run scripts implicitly. However, `stdbuf -o0 bash` runs a complete session with all my scripts and aliases available, and with no output buffering on any of the commands, which is exactly what I wanted. Buffering was of course restored on exit from this `bash` instance. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I liked this so much, I put this first in my .bash_profile. `if [[ "$0" == "-bash" ]]; then exec /usr/bin/stdbuf -i0 -oL -eL /bin/bash -l; fi`

Comment: Worked for me in an `exec` pattern for sending output to a logfile, with all output line buffered rather than buffering fully disabled:
`exec > >(stdbuf -i0 -oL -eL awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0 }' | stdbuf -i0 -oL -eL tee "$LOGFILE") 2>&1`

Comment: @NordicMainframe How can I verify `stdbuf` whether for a specific command or not,say `adb`

Comment: literally every, but openwrt. I bet other "embedded" busybox/toybox linuxes would also lack it.

Answer (score 37):

The command `unbuffer` from the `expect` package disables the output buffering:
[Ubuntu Manpage: unbuffer - unbuffer output](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/expect_unbuffer.1.html)

Example usage:

```
unbuffer hexdump file | ./my_script
```

Comment: unbuffer seems to merge stdout and stderr of the command though... (!)

Comment: @olejorgenb yes it merges stdout and stderr, that's by design: unbuffer uses expect, and expect is there to emulate the human in human-program interaction, and humans don't get to see whether an output is stdout or stderr.

Answer (score 23):

You could also use the `script` command to make the output of `hexdump` line-buffered (`hexdump` will be run in a pseudo terminal which tricks `hexdump` into thinking its writing its stdout to a terminal, and not to a pipe).

```
# cf. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe/
stty -echo -onlcr
script -q /dev/null hexdump file | ./my_script         # FreeBSD, Mac OS X
script -q -c "hexdump file" /dev/null | ./my_script    # Linux
stty echo onlcr
```

Comment: I used the -f parameter to flush, not sure if necessary but it worked.

Comment: In my case, `stdbuf` failed, but script works like a charm. The program  buffers the output when it is being piped to `tee`, but not when running in terminal. So, script works! Thanks!

Comment: Very clever solution, and it works!! Thank you.  :smile:

Comment: Only one problem with that:  per `script`'s `man` page as referenced by [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86902/86927), "Certain interactive commands, such as `vi(1)`, create garbage in the typescript file. Script works best with commands that do not manipulate the screen, the results are meant to emulate a hardcopy terminal."

Answer (score 2):

One should use grep or egrep "--line-buffered" options to solve this. no other tools needed.