# Very strange redirecting stdout and stderr issues can someone explain them?

Tags: shell, stdout, stderr

I have two calls that produce very different output:

Call one:

```
dmake -m _makefile_.m  1>> _results.out 2>> _results.out
```

Call two:

```
dmake -m _makefile_.m >2&1 >_results.out
```

dmake does a compile of sorts and the first call correctly inlines compile errors whereas the second one puts all the compile errors at the top.  I was always of the opinion that both of these were equivalent.  What exactly are the differences between these two calls?  Is this because of buffering?

Comment: Don't you mean `2>&1` rather than `>2&1`?  Was that a typo in your question, or are you really using `>2&1`?

Comment: Yes, it's probably because of buffering.  Output to stderr is typically unbuffered.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered) has some information about forcing stdout to be unbuffered, but it's ugly.

Comment: Really?  What shell are you using?  The `>2&1` syntax doesn't work for me in tcsh, bash, ksh, or zsh.  Could that be the problem?  Does the command create a file called `2`?

Comment: Or did you leave out a comma in your comment ("no, typo in the question")?

Comment: i don't see a file named 2 and the old way appeared to work... just with all the errors at the top.  Maybe you are right.  I didn't write call two and made the incorrect assumption that it had the correct syntax.  I am using ksh by the way 2>&1 is what all my other scripts use.  I am beginning to suspect you are correct Keith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>2&1` is not the right syntax; it will redirect the output of the `dmake` command to a file called `2` (running it in background), then attempt to run a command called `1` with its output redirected to `_results.out`.

You want:

```
dmake -m _makefile_.m >_results.out 2>&1
```

Change `>` to `>>` if you want to append to the file.

I'm not 100% sure whether this will intersperse stdout and stderr the way you want.