# Three | commands in linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, command

Normally in a Linux command you can specify another one to be run at the same time like this:

```
ls | grep "sys"
```

for example. In my case I have this command:

```
urlsnarf -i wlan0
```

and I can edit it like this to show filtered output:

```
urlsnarf -i wlan0 | cut -d\" -f4
```

but I also want to save the output to file and at the same time print text in the console so I edit it like this:

```
urlsnarf -i wlan0 | cut -d\" -f4 | tee output
```

but there is neither an output file nor printed output. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This question would fit better on other StackExchange sites, namely [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/?as=1) and/or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/?as=1)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine what's happening here is the pipe is being buffered.  I haven't seen `urlsnarf` before, but it looks like it's a continuous monitoring process.  According to the following post, you can't easily stop the pipe from being fully buffered:

[How to make output of any shell command unbuffered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered)

The article linked from an answer there is a good read: [buffering in standard streams](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/)