# Linux: stdout and stderr to socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, console

I want to redirect stdout and stderr to a socket that I can then use to remotely monitor the status of my application over Ethernet.  Currently I accomplish this by using ssh and watching the output in the shell console.  I'd prefer to remove the middle man if possible and just send the entire stdout and stderr output to a udp or tcp/ip port and have my monitoring computer connect to it.

I cannot use UART or any other wired connection.  It has to be Ethernet.  Also, if possible, I'd like to accomplish this via a bash script, to prevent having to rebuild my application.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you describe it, it sounds like your going to need either your existing application to open a passive socket and wait for connections, or your going to have to wrap your application in something that sets up a listening socket. [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49936/dev-tcp-listen-instead-of-nc-listen/49947#49947) suggests that is not possible in just Bash, however it does show ways to do it from the command line with netcat or perl. For example you could do something like this with netcat: `nc -l -p <port> -c "tail -F /var/log/blah"`

Answer (score 6):

On the monitored application side, there is a way to redirect both outputs to an outbound connection, using netcat:

`$ ./application 2>&1 | nc <remote-host> <remote-port>`

This way, you're redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` and then pipe it all together to netcat, which will take care of setting up the socket, establish connection with the remote host and all that stuff.

However, bear in mind that you can suffer from `printf()`'s buffering, if that's the function you're using to write to `stdout`. In my local tests, I've seen that the data sent to `stderr` by the application is seen immediately on the other listening end, but on the other hand the data sent to `stdout` is only sent when the application exits or there's enough data in the buffer to flush it all at once. So, if you care about the order and the availability of the info on the monitoring side, I'd suggest you to place calls to `fflush(stdout);` whenever you print something interesting to `stdout`, or replace the calls  to `printf()`, `fprintf()` and the like to `write()`, which does not buffer. The downside is that you have to touch the code of the application, of course, but I don't know any way to externally force flushing of an application's output buffers (i.e. from bash).

Comment: I suggest you change the nc command to `nc -l <port>` to make the application wait for the monitors connections, like the OP described.

Comment: Other ways for unbuffering stdout are described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered

Comment: @thuovila No, I think the `nc` command is right that way, because that happens in the "client", which will connect to the monitoring "server" and send the output of the application to it. That `-l` would make sense in the monitoring "server", but not on this side of the communication (as stated in my first sentence of the post)

Comment: in case someone would like to have them separated, one can use process substitution for `stderr` and `stdout` like this: `$ ./application 2> >(nc <host> <err-port>) > >(nc <host> <out-port>)`