# Unbuffered Bash Output

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that I'm trying to write unbuffered output with.  I have something like this:

```
...
mkfifo $PIPE
for SERVER in ${SERVERS[@]}; do
    ssh $SERVER command >$PIPE &
done

while read LINE; do
    echo ${LINE}
done <$PIPE
```

The problem is that all of the output of the script is buffered.

I know I can use something like `stdbuf` or `unbuffer` to the whole script, but I don't want my users to have to run `stdbuf -o0 -e0 my_command` every time.

Is there a way to achieve that effect within my script?

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: Well, you could of course always have your script execute itself in the appropriate environment, leaving this detail hidden from your users.  There might be a better solution, though.

Comment: a stupid question here: what does `unbuffered` mean here? like stderr flushed by char?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make output of any shell command unbuffered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3465619/608639)

Answer (score 1):

*Why not create an alias to run `stdbuf`, which will in turn unbuffer the script output?*

I understand you don't want the user to manually input the command with `stdbuf`. Why not let the user create an alias which will execute `stdbuf` running the script?

```
alias my_script='stdbuf -o0 -e0 <path_to_script>'
```

Now users can run the script from the terminal (terminal can also help to fill out script name) as follows:

```
my_script
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `stdbuf` on the script won't help; it won't apply to all of the commands inside the script.

The right place for `stdbuf` is at the command generating the output, i. e.

```
    ssh $SERVER stdbuf -o0 -e0 command >$PIPE &
```