# How to flush contents in shell pipes?

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

When typing such a command:

```
find . -type f -iname "*part*"
```

I get, slowly, file names appearing, as soon as they're found -- one at a time.

Adding a `sed` expression behind it...

```
find . -type f -iname "*part*" | sed "s#^\./##"
```

… delays the display up to the end of the `find` command, *then* processing everything at once.

How to avoid that?  How to flush to `sed`?

**PS-** Alternatively, how to remove the `./` prefix from every line, without delaying the display?

Comment: [How to make output of any shell command unbuffered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3465619/608639), [Unbuffered Bash Output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27257320/608639), [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372), [Force flushing of output to a file while bash script is still running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1429951/608639), [How to correctly unbuffer a pipeline?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/386987) and friends.

Comment: Use `find . -type f -iname "*part*" -printf '%P\n'` to strip the `./` prefixes at the source.

Comment: @JohnKugelmansupportsMonica Thanks a lot!  That did it. For whichever reason which escapes me, none of the awk / stdbuf solutions did work -- they still delayed the sed up to the end. Your solution solves this. (Any idea why stdbuf did not work?)

Comment: Did you apply `stdbuf -oL` to `find`?

Comment: I did `find … | stdbuf -oL sed …`

Comment: Apply it to `find` instead. The buffering is on the output side of the pipe not the input side.

Comment: You're completely right: `stdbuf -oL find … | sed …`does the job. Thanks a lot for this information! (and your better solution)