# Bash not waiting for full results after pipe but immediate action on direct output

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, tail

When using `grep -r "something" .`, it will print to output as something gets found.

Whenever using a pipe afterwards to postprocess, it will wait though until having received all the output.

Is there some way / syntax for piping per line as it gets available?

Don't bother with improving the example, it really is just an example:

```
grep -r "something" . | grep -v "somethingelse"  # excluding somethingelse
```

The result will only be there after everything has been searched (because of the pipe `|`), but I'm looking for syntax which would respond on each line from `grep -r "something" .` as the "line becomes available".

It's possible to pipe to a program that waits for input and handles anything that reaches it, but using the pipe will only send data to it as it is done completely?

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You can use `unbuffer` command if you have `expect` package installed. Similar issue was discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered)

Comment: @BalajiSukumaran Indeed that's a duplicate, didn't know the terminology to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `grep` you can use `--line-buffered` option. If program does not have a similar option, you can use `stdbuf` program, e.g.:

```
tail -f access.log | stdbuf -oL cut -d ' ' -f1 | uniq
```

In this example `stdbuf` runs `cut` program with its output stream modified to be line buffered.

Comment: Doesn't the pipe make us wait for the tailing to stop (which it wouldn't) before showing results?

Comment: it is not pipe that makes us wait. it is buffering mode of output stream attached to that pipe that does.

Comment: Why does `grep -rs "a" / | /usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin/stdbuf -oL echo "$(date)` yield only 1 line of output?

Comment: because `echo` does not read stdin at all, so it useless after pipe, unless you pass it arguments from stdin with `xargs`, e.g. `cat somefile | xargs echo $(date)`

Comment: `grep -rsZ a / | xargs -0L1 echo $(date)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep`'s `--line-buffered` option:

> ```
> --line-buffered
>          Force output to be line buffered.  By default, output is line
>          buffered when standard output is a terminal and block buffered
>          otherwise.
> ```

Comment: I'm looking for a more general option than only in `grep`, though it is a nice find.