# Chronologically capturing STDOUT and STDERR

Tags: linux, unix, sh, tee

This very well may fall under KISS (keep it simple) principle but I am still curious and wish to be educated as to why I didn't receive the expected results. So, here we go...

I have a shell script to capture STDOUT and STDERR without disturbing the original file descriptors. This is in hopes of preserving the original order of output (see `test.pl` below) as seen by a user on the terminal.

Unfortunately, I am limited to using sh, instead of bash (but I welcome examples), as I am calling this from another suite and I may wish to use it in a cron in the future (I know cron has the `SHELL` environment variable).

`wrapper.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
stdout_and_stderr=$1
shift
command=$@

out="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/out.$$"
err="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/err.$$"
mkfifo ${out} ${err}
trap 'rm ${out} ${err}' EXIT
> ${stdout_and_stderr}
tee -a ${stdout_and_stderr} < ${out} &
tee -a ${stdout_and_stderr} < ${err} >&2 &
${command} >${out} 2>${err}
```

`test.pl` contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "1: stdout1\n";
print STDERR "2: stderr1\n";
print "3: stdout2\n";
```

In the scenario:

```
sh wrapper.sh /tmp/xxx perl test.pl
```

STDOUT contains:

```
1: stdout1
3: stdout2
```

STDERR contains:

```
2: stderr1
```

All good so far...

`/tmp/xxx` contains:

```
2: stderr1
1: stdout1
3: stdout2
```

However, I was expecting `/tmp/xxx` to contain:

```
1: stdout1
2: stderr1
3: stdout2
```

Can anyone explain to me why STDOUT and STDERR are not appending `/tmp/xxx` in the order that I expected? My guess would be that the backgrounded `tee` processes are blocking the `/tmp/xxx` resource from one another since they have the same "destination". How would you solve this?

related: [How do I write stderr to a file while using "tee" with a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe)

Comment: Whatever you do here, if one of the `tee`s gets blocked for a while (because of heavy load on the system, or whatever), the data that goes through it will also be delayed. There's really no way around that, as the output from the process contains no ordering or timestamps that could be used to arrange the writes correctly at the other end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a feature of the C runtime library (and probably is imitated by other runtime libraries) that `stderr` is not buffered.  As soon as it is written to, stderr pushes all of its characters to the destination device.

By default `stdout` has a 512-byte buffer.

The buffering for both `stderr` and `stdout` can be changed with the [`setbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setbuf) or [`setvbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf) calls.

From the Linux man page for stdout:

> NOTES: The stream stderr is unbuffered.  The stream  stdout  is  line-buffered when  it  points  to  a  terminal.  Partial lines will not appear until fflush(3) or exit(3) is called, or a newline is printed.  This can produce unexpected results, especially with debugging output.  The buffering mode of the standard streams (or any other stream) can  be changed using  the  setbuf(3) or setvbuf(3) call.  Note that in case stdin is associated with a terminal, there may also be input buffering in the terminal driver, entirely unrelated to stdio buffering.  (Indeed, normally terminal input is line buffered  in  the  kernel.)   This  kernel input handling can be modified using calls like tcsetattr(3); see also stty(1), and termios(3).

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit more searching, inspired by @wallyk, I made the following modification to `wrapper.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
stdout_and_stderr=$1
shift
command=$@

out="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/out.$$"
err="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/err.$$"
mkfifo ${out} ${err}
trap 'rm ${out} ${err}' EXIT
> ${stdout_and_stderr}
tee -a ${stdout_and_stderr} < ${out} &
tee -a ${stdout_and_stderr} < ${err} >&2 &
script -q -F 2 ${command} >${out} 2>${err}
```

Which now produces the expected:

```
1: stdout1
2: stderr1
3: stdout2
```

The solution was to prefix the `$command` with `script -q -F 2` which makes `script` quite (`-q`) and then forces file descriptor 2 (STDOUT) to flush immediately (`-F 2`).

I am now researching to determine how portable this is. I think `-F pipe` may be Mac and FreeBSD and `-f` or `--flush` may be other distros...

related: [How to make output of any shell command unbuffered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered)

Comment: now i'm struggling with argument expansion from the calling script. i'm attempting to write the command to a tmp file and have wrapper.sh read it but this in just becoming more trouble than it's worth. maybe someone will find another use for this though