# c++ popen makes the application to halt for 30 seconds

Tags: c++11, ros

I am trying to parse a stream by using popen with a command that returns a **constant stream** of output lines.

This makes the application to get stuck on the `fgets()` call.

Here's the method:

```
std::string MyClass::InvokeCmd(std::string command)
{
    std::string result;
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    FILE *pipe = popen(command.c_str(), "r");

        while (fgets(buffer.data(), 128, pipe) != NULL)
        {
            result += buffer.data();
        }
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

The command is a ROS command:

> rostopic hz /topicname

The command runs continuously and produces one line of output approximately  every second.

If I wait for around 30 sec (looks like flush time of a buffer) I do see the data.

Comment: Your code does not show the actual command. Is it real code?

Comment: Hi @Arkadiy, looks like it is getting stuck on the while.
However I noticed that if I wait for around 30 sec (looks like flush time of a buffer) I do see the data.

The command is rostopic hz /topicname

Comment: Does the command produce output immediately if it's run in command line?

Comment: Yes, it prints a line every second.

Comment: Correct. I am getting the same latency with the cat piped to it. Is there anyhing that can done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like buffering inside the `rostopic` utility. When stdout goes to a terminal, many C libraries are smart enough to flush every time `'\n'` is written. When stdout goes to a pipe, the library would add a large buffer. Looks like it takes 30 seconds to fill it.

To test this theory, try `rostopic hz /topicname | cat` in command line.

There is not much that can be done, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered) question.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you pit some asserting that pipe is not nullptr. If it is nullptr, then perhaps print out command, errno and strerror().