# Bash commands piped to awk are sometimes buffered

Tags: linux, bash, awk, mawk

System: Linux 4.13.0-43-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu 
BASH_VERSION='4.3.48(1)-release'

The command:

```
while sleep 5
do
  date +%T
done | awk -F: '{print $3}'
```

Should print the 3rd field (seconds) of the "date" output, one line every 5 seconds. Problem: awk reads from the pipe, and processes its input, only when the pipe's buffer is full. i.e. when more than 4K of input is generated.

When *awk* is replaced by *cat*, a line is printed every 5 seconds as expected.

This code snippet is simplified from a shell script which had worked ok on other systems, so there must be something about bash, awk and their configuration in this system.

In short, is there a way to convince *awk* to behave like *cat* when reading from a pipe?

@Ed Morton : I did try to add *fflush()* after each print, but it does not work -- that's what showed that the problem is with awk's input, not output.
I also tried to add calls to *system("date")*, which showed that indeed awk gets all input lines at once, not immediately when they are produced.

For those who asked:

```
$ awk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040
```

Comment: The awk version is more pertinent than the bash version here. That said, I can't reproduce this at all -- and indeed, it **shouldn't** be reproducible, as `date` necessarily flushes its output before it can exit.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a Dockerfile where the issue reproduces as-described? I've tried two separate environments, and the code sample in this question behaves properly.

Comment: The problem may be related to the surrounding code which you trimmed away, e.g. if you're piping the awk output to another command. In any case, try adding a call to fflush() after the print to see if that helps - `{print $3; fflush()}`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#I_002fO-Functions for details

Comment: When you simplify code, please make sure to test it *after* you simplify. This helps ensure you don't accidentally remove the relevant parts.

Comment: Hi, it does work for me, I've also tried `while sleep 5; do date +%T | cut -d: -f3;done`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered

Answer (score 5):

While trying to find out how to make *awk* print its version, I discovered that it is really *mawk*, and that it has the following flag:

```
 -W interactive -- sets unbuffered writes to stdout and line buffered reads from stdin.
                   Records from stdin are lines regardless of the value of RS.
```

This seems to solve the problem!

Thanks to all repliers.

Answer (score 0):

[stdbuf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) is a general solution:

> stdbuf - Run COMMAND, with modified buffering operations for its standard streams.

```bash
# buffered
while sleep 5; do date +%T; done | awk -F: '{print $0, strftime("%T")}' | ts %T

# unbuffered
while sleep 5; do date +%T; done | stdbuf -oL awk -F: '{print $0, strftime("%T")}' | ts %T
```

Please install `moreutils` to get `ts`