# C: popen reading from stdout blocks

Tags: c, popen

[The manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) for `popen` says "reading from a "popened" stream reads the command's standard output".

However, I can't seem to get the subprocess output in the trivial program below.  The "reader" parent process blocks on the read (whether using `fgets` or `fread`)

What am I missing?

Attaching to the *pinger* program with gdb shows it is looping and calling printf to output text. Just nothing detected by `fgets` on the parent's side...

**PINGER.C**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("stdout %d\n", i++);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

**POPENTEST.C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *cmd = "./pinger";
    printf("Running '%s'\n", cmd);

    FILE *fp = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        perror("popen failed:");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("fp open\n");

    char inLine[1024];
    while (fgets(inLine, sizeof(inLine), fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Received: '%s'\n", inLine);
    }

    printf("feof=%d ferror=%d: %s\n", feof(fp), ferror(fp), strerror(errno));
    pclose(fp);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$ ./popenTest
fp open
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, C buffers writes to the stdout when stdout is not connected to a tty. This means that from the OS' perspective, the program has not written anything to stdout until either the buffer is full or you manually flushed the output:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("stdout %d\n", i++);
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

When connected to a tty, the stdout is automatically flushed on every newline. But this automatic flushing does not happen when the stdout is connected to a pipe.

Comment: C also buffers write to stdout by default when it is connected to a tty, but it is line buffered rather than block buffered.

Comment: duh, yes of course.  Thank you.  In the real case, the source of the data is a 3rd party program I don't control, so buffering is inevitable. What is the buffer size? (or how to find out?)

Comment: @Danny: many programs accepts command-line flags to control buffering, that's usually the best way to do this. However, if you can't, then there are [a few hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered) you can do.

Comment: Good idea.  The actual program is `ffmpeg`, which has the `-flush_packets` flag.  That should do the trick.  Thanks.

Comment: Any ideas on finding errors in the child would be appreciated. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56503915/c-c-detect-fault-in-popen-child-process