# C Detect fault in popen child process

Tags: c, popen

I'm using `popen` to read the output of a third party program.  I'd like to detect and restart things if the sub-program fails.

How would I do that?  If the child dies, the process didn't exit normally and therefore can't use `WEXITSTATUS` to check.

Is there another way?

Here's a simple example:

**PINGER.C**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        //fprintf(stderr, "StdErr %d\n", i);
        printf("stdout %d\n", i++);
        fflush(stdout);

        if (i == 5)
            i = i / 0; // Die a horrible death

        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

**WATCHER.C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *cmd = "./pinger";
    printf("Running '%s'\n", cmd);

    FILE *fp = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        perror("popen failed:");
        exit(1);
    }

    char inLine[1024];
    int  bytesRead = 0;
    int  i = 0;

    while (fgets(inLine, sizeof(inLine), fp) != NULL)
    {
        int len = strlen(inLine);
        if (inLine[len-1] == '\n')
            inLine[len-1] = '\0';

        printf("Received: '%s'\n", inLine);
    }

    printf("feof=%d ferror=%d: %s\n", feof(fp), ferror(fp), strerror(errno));

    int rc = pclose(fp);
    printf("pclose returned: %d. IFEXITED=%d\n", rc, WIFEXITED(rc));
}
```

Here's the output:

```
$ ./popenTest
calling popen
Running './pinger'
pipe open
Received: 'stdout 0'
Received: 'stdout 1'
Received: 'stdout 2'
Received: 'stdout 3'
Received: 'stdout 4'
feof=1 ferror=0: Success
pclose returned: 8. IFEXITED=0 EXITSTATUS=0
```

([According to this post](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.15/gtpc2/cpp_wexitstatus.html), you actually can't use `WEXITSTATUS` if the command didn't exit normally, but I tried anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the POSIX specification of [`pclose()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pclose.html) (and [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) too).  It says:

> **Return value**
>
> Upon successful return, `pclose()` shall return the termination status of the command language interpreter. Otherwise, `pclose()` shall return -1 and set `errno` to indicate the error.

Thus, you can get the exit status of the process indirectly via the return value of `pclose()`.  That will be a number between 0 and 255.  Shells often report the 'death of a child by signal' by returning the value `128 + signal_number`.  The specification outlines circumstances in which the status may not be available (your program called `wait()` and got the information for the process opened by `popen()` before you called `pclose()`, for example).  Reading the specification of `popen()` explains the use of 'the command language interpreter' in the specification of `pclose()`.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful.  It explains why `pclose` returned 8. That is SIGFPE, corresponding to the divide by zero!

Comment: If `popen()` didn't need to invoke a shell, then you'd get a raw 16-bit integer containing the exit status in the more significant 8 bits or the signal number in the less significant 8 bits — hence you might get the value 8 for the process dying of signal 8 (FPE).

Answer (score 0):

A process returns an exit status by returning from its main() with an exit code, or by calling _exit(statuscode). If the process is terminated abnormally, for example due to a signal or a fault, the process never gets a chance to do any of those, so there is no exitstatus.

In that case, all you can know is that the process terminates with an error.

If you want to restart on all cases where a program terminates on error, you need to check both WIFEXITED and WEXITSTATUS:

```
do {
    rc = run_your_child_process();

} while (!WIFEXITED(rc) || WEXITSTATUS(rc) == 0);

// child terminated without error
```