# How can dmenu show input as soon as there is input from pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dmenu

TL;DR

Here is the default behavior.

```sh
find ~/ -name *.git 2>/dev/null | dmenu
# Searches everything in home directory and shows output
```

Time taken about 1-2 sec

What I want:

```sh
find ~/ -name *.git 2>/dev/null | less
# Show as soon as it finds result. How to get similar output in dmenu?
```

As files in my PC will increase, this is going to take longer time.

Detailed description:

I am piping input into `dmenu` from a `find` command which takes about 1-2 seconds. Is it possible for `dmenu` to show input as soon as there is some input in the pipe. Because that's the basic working of piping. It seems like `dmenu` waits until there are all the entries in pipe so that user can search from it which also looks legit, but still can this be avoided? I would like to run `dmenu` as soon as there is input in buffer.

Comment: Not necessarily all entries, but as many entries until the stdout from `find` gets flushed. In theory you would need the stdout being unbuffered. I have not tried this yet, but if this is Linux, or MacOS with the Gnu Coreutils installed,  I would try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered#25548995) approach.

Comment: I am using it on a Linux machine. `stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 find ~/ -name *.git 2>/dev/null | dmenu` takes same amount of time and so does `find ~/ -name *.git 2>/dev/null | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 dmenu`. (didn't know which is correct so tried both ways!)

Comment: Since you want to unbuffer `find`, the former one looks more sensible for me, but I would combine both, just for a try: Doing the stdout from `find` unbuffered, and the stdin fron `dmenu`.

Comment: Thinking of it .... Of course if `dmenu` itself chooses to swallow the whole input before doing something, there isn't anything you can do, unless `dmenu` itself provides an option to change this behaviour, because this is then not related to buffering anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found some workaround to decrease time against `find` here. Instead of `find`, `locate` can be used. So the command goes like

```sh
locate -r '/home'"$USER"'.*\.git$'
```

`-r` takes input a regular expression. Arguments to `-r` here filters all git repositories inside `/home/$USER`. This is a bit faster than using `find`.

#### Catch using `locate`

`locate` uses a local database for searching. So it will only work as expected when local database will be built/updated.

To update database, use `sudo updatedb`. Whenever you add/move/delete a file (or a directory in this case), remember to update database for `locate` to give proper results.

> **Tip**
>
> To avoid entering password every time for `updatedb` (and other frequently used commands), add them to *sudoers* by executing `sudo visudo` and adding entry for path to command's binary's location

### Update

I recently realized why use `locate` when I can simply maintain my own database and cat all the entries to `dmenu`. With this I was able to achieve what I needed.

```sh
# Make a temp directory
 mkdir -p $HOME/.tmp
# Search for all git directories and store them in ~/.tmp/gitfies. 
[ -e $HOME/.tmp/gitfiles ] || find $HOME/ -regex .*/\.git$ -type d 2>/dev/null > $HOME/.tmp/gitfiles
# cat this file into dmenu
cat $HOME/.tmp/gitfiles | dmenu
```

This gives a fuzzy finding for directories with `dmenu`. This is better than using `locate` as even in `locate` you need to update local database and so in here. Since we do the filtering of git files at runtime with `locate`, it is a bit slower than this case.

I can simple create an alias to update this database analogous to `sudo updatedb` in case of `locate`, by

```sh
alias gitdbupdate="find $HOME/ -regex .*/\.git$ -type d 2>/dev/null > $HOME/.tmp/gitfiles"
```

Note that I am not using `/tmp/` as it won't be persistent across power cycles. So rather I create my own `$HOME/.tmp/` directory.

Comment: Or add yourself to the `wheel` group (or `sudo` group on some distros) and then uncomment the final line (or next to final line) using `# visudo` to allows `wheel` group members to execute any command without a password. (there is a similar 2-line addition to `/etc/pam.d/su` to allow members of `wheel` to `su` without a password)