# sed works differently for a tail -f vs tail?

Tags: linux, sed, grep, redhat

I have a log file that is line separated by \n with multi-line logs (ones containing SQL) being separated by \r\n. In order to pull the SQL statements out of the file I need to convert the \r\n to \s. Not knowing sed I googled and found a good solution that works very well but it fails when I switch to tail -f.

eg. these work:

```
tail -1000 /mylogfile.log | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n/ /g' | grep "Executing command"
cat /mylogfile.log | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n/ /g' | grep "Executing command"
```

but this returns no data at all

```
tail -f /mylogfile.log | sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n/ /g' | grep "Executing command"
```

EDIT: For the person who added a "This question already has an answer here:", no that does not answer the question at all. First, that other question wasn't even resolved for the person who asked it. Second, it talks only about grep, the problem is with sed. I can have 10 greps and it still works fine if I switch from sed to perl. eg

```
tail -f /mylog.log | perl -ne 's/\r\n/ /g; print;' | grep "Executing command" | grep -vi ANALYZE | grep -vi DESCRIBE | grep -vi "SHOW PARTITION"
```

Comment: Maybe try `sed -u` for unbuffered output.

Comment: Or use [stdbuf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25548995/402322).

Comment: You probably want to replace `sed | grep` with an Awk script.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried sed -u but didn't help

Comment: @triplee I prefer to keep the grep separate as it will make it easier to change in the future.

Comment: `awk -v expr="Executing command" '$0 ~ expr { ... }'`

Comment: Thanks, I still think the grep is more readable, possibly because I've never bothered to learn awk. I ended up just using the perl solution as that works and is sort of readable.