# Bash script write stdout and stderr to terminal and separate log files

Tags: bash, shell

I want to create a bash script which does following:

- write stdout and stderr to terminal
- write stdout and stderr to info.log and prefix it with date and time
- write stderr to error.log and prefix it with date and time
- call multiple other bash scripts and exit if one does not exit with 0
- exit with same exit code from first failing script

In my current script, the output in the terminal is not in chronological order... seems that the redirection with `tee` does something asynchronous.

Here is my current script:

```
#!/bin/bash

info_log_path="info.log"
error_log_path="error.log"

bashtrap()
{
   echo "Job finished with Exitcode $?"; exit $?;
}

trap bashtrap EXIT ERR

#exit on first errror:
#set -e

# redirect stdout and stderr to info log
exec &> >( tee >(while IFS= read -r line; do printf '[%s] %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "$line"; done >>"$info_log_path"))
# redirect stderr to error log
exec 2> >( tee >(while IFS= read -r line; do printf '[%s] %s\n' "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')" "$line"; done >>"$error_log_path"))

echo "Executing script1"
./script1

echo "Executing script2"
./script2

echo "Executing script3"
./script3

echo "Executing script4"
./script4
```

Comment: You set your trap for `EXTI`, not for `ERR`. The latter is what would give you `set -e` behavior. Though why don't you simply use `set -e`?

Comment: thx the trap mistake solved the first problem :)

Comment: There is no way really to ensure that stderr and stdout print in a specific order. You can probably get something close to what you hope for by disabling buffering.

Comment: how could i do that? without redirection the output is in order... it should be possible that redirection is sequential too

Comment: I think its because of exec... Can i redirect the output without exec?

Comment: The `exec` is not the problem. Google output buffering.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered

Comment: Note that `while read; do print $(date)` will  be _very_ slow. Consider using `awk` for adding timestamp to lines _magnitudes_ faster.

Comment: i tried to get rid of buffering with ´´´stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0´´´ but it did not work. any ideas? where i need to disable buffering?