# Kotlin forEach sometimes not executing until CTL-C when run in the REPL?

Tags: kotlin

When running the following code as a snippet  from  https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/examples/convert-list-array :

```
   
    // printing elements of the array list
    vowels_list.forEach { System.out.print(it) }


   // vowels array
    val vowels_array: Array<String> = arrayOf("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
    
    // converting array to array list
    val vowels_list: List<String> = vowels_array.toList()
    
    // printing elements of the array list
    vowels_list.forEach { System.out.print(it) }
```

The output is supposed to be `aeiou`

However when I am running it in the `kotlin` REPL nothing is printed. Why is that?

**Update**  There seems to be something going on for the `kotlin repl` itself.  I just noticed there is a bracket - as if the code were not completed yet:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have to hit `CTL-C` and then we see this:

```
aeiou<interrupted>
```

What is happening here?

Comment: The above code works fine for me in Kotlin REPL. I don't it's a problem with the code. It is probably an issue with your IDEA. This makes no sense but can you remove the comments and try again. It's a long shot

Comment: I'm running this in the REPL - which is noted in the question. I'll add that to the title since it seems to be the real problem

Comment: The issue might be in the buffering of the terminal where you are running REPL. Try to add `println()` to the end of your code.

Comment: @KonstantinRaspopov OK  yes that solved it. Please make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the buffering of the terminal. You may add `println()` to the end of your code to force flushing the symbols to the screen.

Comment: btw Did you run into any way to disable output buffering in the REPL?

Comment: @StephenBoesch as far as I know, there's no easy way to do it. Also, it depends on your OS. You can try some approaches from this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/3465619/2314529

Comment: This isn't specifically an REPL issue.  It's very common for text output to be line-buffered; stdout is on most operating systems (though not stderr).  So it's good practice to write a trailing newline character (e.g. by using `println()`).  In fact, on Unix a text file is always assumed to end with a newline, and some tools may ignore anything after the last newline.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to run only the last three lines of code?
I did it by running on https://play.kotlinlang.org/ and it printed `aeiou`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it is working in a different environment. There seems to be something funny about `kotlin` REPL. See my question update

Comment: I haven't worked REPL so far, I used the kotlin sandbox provided by JetBrains and I've coded kotlin projects in Intellij IDEA.