# Realtime stdout in golang when executing binary

Tags: go

**Premise:**

I know there are a handful of questions touching on this, but after looking through them (and implementing every answer), I'm at a bit of a loss.

I have a binary (`showkey`), that I'd like to process the output of in realtime, in order to let a secondary system know when a key has been both pressed, and released.

**Setup:**

- Raspberry pi
- Physical GPIO connection to a digital I/O system on the secondary hardware
- Keyboard plugged into Rpi
- Golang code on Rpi to monitor key actuation and release, and switch a GPIO pin up/down

**Code:**

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"os/exec"
"bufio"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Tracking Input!")
    
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/showkey", "-k")
    pipe, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(pipe)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        m := scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println(m)
    }

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

**Issue:**

The current code (and every other iteration I've tried after reading through every other question posted) does not in fact allow golang to process the data. the `fmt.Println(m)` prints out after the showkey binary ends (10 seconds after last key press).

I've confirmed through the showkey source code that it prints to stdout, and am really at a loss here. The `fmt.Println("Tracking Inputs!")` statement comes through, and then nothing until showkey stops (though showkey does in fact track the key presses as it's supposed to), when everything is printed at once.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How does showkey reads keys? From the terminal? If you exec it like this, it won't have a terminal attached.

Comment: Also be aware that you are forcing the output to be line buffered by the fact that you are reading the output by scanning for lines.

Comment: Some commands buffer output when stdout is not a terminal. If showkeys is one of those commands, then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3465619/5728991) may  help.

Comment: take a look at https://tinygo.org to manage RPi hardware , it's super easy working with gpio

Comment: And combine a library like this one to listen for keystrokes https://github.com/eiannone/keyboard

Comment: @BurakSerdar it uses IOCTL to read, and outputs directly to stdout for press and release

Comment: @JimB yeah, that's fine - the purpose of this is to get the press and release time which will be used in conjunction with a robotic arm pressing the key (very slowly)

Comment: @wakumaku very familiar with RPi+GPIO stuff (I cut out my GPIO code from this for clarity), and that library doesn't provide release events which I need

Comment: @CeriseLimón You're a legend! That was in fact the issue, and using stdbuf as per one of the answers has easily resolved the situation. If you want to throw an answer down I'll mark it correct :)

Comment: Are you aware that this question was closed as duplicate by Cerise Limon themselves with the very link in their comment? So the remark you added to your question to have it reopened seems contradictory. I rolled back your edit on the grounds that you confirmed you were able to find a solution with Cerise's link.