# Bash function can indent piped lines multiple times without waiting for whole input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

What I want to achieve:

- Define a function that can be used to pipe input, such as `echo input | my_function`
- This function modifies every inputted line, e.g., it adds indentation at the beginning.
- This function can be reused twice and in that case does its modification (double indent) twice, e.g. `echo input | my_function | my_function` results in `\t\tinput`.
- This function does not wait for whole input to be supplied, it can print out the line directly without seeing all input.

As for my test, please see the following script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

main() {
  echo 'first:'
  echo 'once' | tab_indent_to_right
  echo 'twice' | tab_indent_to_right | tab_indent_to_right
  {
    echo 'wait 2 sec'
    sleep 2
    echo 'wait 2 sec'
    sleep 2
    echo 'waited'
  } | tab_indent_to_right
}

tab_indent_to_right() {
  # while read -r line; do echo $'\t'"$line"; done  #  double indent not working
  # awk -v prefix='\t' '{print prefix $0}'          #  buffer not working
  # sed 's/^/\t/'                                   #  buffer not working
  # xargs -I {} echo $'\t{}'                        #  double indent not working
  # xargs -L1 echo $'\t'                            #  double indent not working
}

main
```

Each line in `tab_indent_to_right` is my failed attempt to solve the problem. They have two different problems, either:

- Double indent is not working e.g., `tab_indent_to_right | tab_indent_to_right`
- Or, the lines are not being flushed/printed directly but instead being buffered. In other words, the function waits for all `sleep`s and prints out everything at once, instead of printing the lines as they come.

How can I create this function so both double calls gives me the modification I want and also the script does not wait for complete execution of the piped shell?

Comment: See [How to make output of any shell command unbuffered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3465619/4154375).  The mechanisms described in the answers could be used to with `sed` or `awk`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to set `IFS` to nothing to keep spaces/tabs.

```
tab_indent_to_right() {
  while IFS= read -r line; do echo $'\t'"$line"; done
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In recentish versions of `awk`, you can use the `fflush()` function to force it to send output lines immediately:

```
awk -v prefix='\t' '{print prefix $0; fflush()}'
```

Also, depending on the version of `sed` you have, you may be able to add either the `-u` flag (for "unbuffered"; GNU `sed` supports this) or the `-l` flag ("line buffered"; bsd `sed` supports this). If you have some other version of `sed`... check its `man` page to see if it has a similar option.

BTW, the bsd version of `sed` doesn't support `\t` for tab; but if you use `$'s/^/\t/'`, bash will convert `\t` to tab before passing it to `sed`. This works with both versions of `sed`, but not with shells that don't support ANSI quoting mode (i.e. dash).