# Can I trust shell's `read` to not buffer input?

Tags: bash, shell, posix

```
seq 99999 | (head -n2; cat) | head -n5 
1
2

1861
1862
```

In the above example, `head -n2` reads much more than two lines, so `cat` misses out on them.

Using `read` does not have this problem:

```
seq 99999 | (for i in 1 2; do read -r s; printf %s\\n "$s"; done; cat) | head -n5
1
2
3
4
5
```

The question is: can this be relied upon?

I have tried reading about POSIX [read](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) and [shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/shell.html) without finding the answer.

(What I really want is approximately: `a_program | (sed 's/A/B/;7q'; cat) | program_b`, where I modify first ~7 lines (text), then cat the rest (incl. binary). If `read` works, that's fine, but I want to know how safe it is.)

Comment: I don't think that it is specified that `head` terminates immediately after the required number of lines has been read. Furthermore, standard input by default undergoes buffering. Without any buffering, peeking at the next character (without consuming it) would not work. You can turn off buffering for a speciric command: See _man stdbuf_.

Comment: Maybe [disabling buffering entirely in your terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered) solves this issue entirely?

Comment: Why not just `a_program | sed '1,7s/A/B/' | program_b`, i.e. don't split the middle part across multiple tools?

Comment: You may be interested in [can-head-read-consume-more-input-lines-than-it-outputs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/750523/can-head-read-consume-more-input-lines-than-it-outputs) by the way.

Comment: Thank you both for very relevant links. @EdMorton Because sed failed with `illegal byte sequence`, util I tried with line number addresses like your example - which seems to work! (Still theoretically interesting though, perhaps `dd` could also work?)

Comment: What any given sed might do with binary data is an interesting question - you'd have to read the man page for the version you use. You might also have to set `LC_ALL=C` when you call it. GNU awk can handle binary data see [BINMODE](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#User_002dmodified) or other mentions of "binary" in the manual) and has far more abilities than `sed` for transforming data. Idk about `dd`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can depend on the `read` built-in to (appear to) not buffer input.  Normal operation is for `read` to take input a byte at a time to ensure that it does not read past the next newline character.

Some shells (including Bash) have an optimization whereby they read blocks of data at a time but they use "seek" to position the file input position back to just after the next newline. However, "seek" cannot be used with some inputs (including input from pipes, named pipes (aka FIFOs), and sockets) so the optimization is not applicable and reading has to be done byte-by-byte, which is slow. The `read` commands in the code in the question are taking input from a pipe so they will read byte-by-byte.

For more technical details, see the [answer by Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282706/264812) to [Why some shells `read` builtin fail to read the whole line from file in `/proc`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/282701/264812) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).  (Relevant information starts at paragraph 3).

Also see [head eats extra characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/409462/264812).

Comment: I agree that many or all implementations do this. It also seems logical to me. But I wish the POSIX spec was more clear. In [Shell & Utilities - Utility Description Defaults](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_04) has an example similar to my case: `cat file | (sed -n 1q; cat)`, and says "command leaves the file offset in the open file description in an unspecified state. Other utilities, such as head, read, and sh, have similar properties." - `read` is explicitly mentioned.