# maven log file configuration

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-3

How can I configure logging for maven build? The log which maven generates is not providing enought information like time stamp with each log statement. Where/what log config file maven uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This still seems some *closed* issue in Maven, as you can see on:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-519

The provided workaround looks not too bad, but you need to modify the maven installation.

Answer (score 8):

You may be aware of this, and it will not print dates, but use `mvn -X` to print verbose output.

Additionally, you can always pipe the output of maven to some other utility (assuming your shell environment contains halfway competent tools).  For instance  `mvn -X clean | awk '{print "("d")"$0}' "d=$(date)"` prints out a date before each line in maven.  I didn't bother formatting the date, but that's easily done with arguments to the `date` executable.  Note that this won't really work for maven commands that require interactive user input, such as `maven archetype:generate`.

Answer (score 5):

Answer provided by @whaley is a good direction. However, the $(date) is evaluated only once at the beginning and then remains the same.
I had to use an approach mentioned in [Is there a Unix utility to prepend timestamps to stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-lines-of-text):

```
mvn -X <goals> | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }'
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @eckes, default logging configuration file is available at /conf/logging/simplelogger.properties, from Maven 3.1.0 onward.

Change "org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime" property value to "true"

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true
```

To change dateTimeFormat, as default is relative time in milliseconds.
Add below line in simplelogger.properties file.

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.dateTimeFormat=HH:mm:ss:SSS
```

References: 
Maven logging: https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html 
DateFormats: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

Maven in Version 3.1 and 3.2 allow simpler configuration of the SLF4J based logger. You can specify "-l logfile" on the command line, and the default configuration of the SimpleLogger is in the config file `conf/logging/simplelogger.properties`.

If you want to turn on the default timestampts (milliseconds since start) you can simple change the property in this file: `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true`.

Comment: But `-l` is "log file to where all build output will go", not the logging configuration.

Comment: @lexicore yes, this is what I said "-l logfile"

Comment: I am looking for change the build log to a file, mvn -l logfile works for me.