# Redirect stderr with log file from cron

Tags: python, shell, logging, cron

I am referring to [Redirect stderr with date to log file from Cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145544/redirect-stderr-with-date-to-log-file-from-cron).

Basically, I have the following files.

```
root@ubuntu:/home/osaka# ls -l cronlog.sh python_1.py shellscript_2.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 153 Oct 19 16:49 cronlog.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 694 Oct 19 18:28 python_1.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  96 Oct 19 18:27 shellscript_2.sh
```

The `python_1.py` calling `shellscript_2.sh` from within it script:

```
#python_1.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys, subprocess

def command():
    return os.system('/home/osaka/shellscript_2.sh')

print "This is " + sys.argv[0]
command()
```

And this is the content of `cronlog.sh` exactly from the reciert #7145544:

```
#cronlog.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "[`date +\%F-\%T`] Start executing $1"
"$@" 2>&1 | sed -e "s/\(.*\)/[`date +\%F-\%T`] \1/"
echo "[`date +\%F-\%T`] End executing $1"
```

And I have cronjob to run this and redirected to the log file, but no matter what I have tried the content from `shellscript_2.sh` got written to log first instead of `python_1.py`.

Here's the sample log output:

```
[2012-10-19-18:45:31] Start executing /home/achinnac/osaka/python_1.py
[2012-10-19-18:45:31] This is /home/achinnac/osaka/shellscript_2.sh
[2012-10-19-18:45:31] This is /home/achinnac/osaka/python_1.py
[2012-10-19-18:45:31] End executing /home/achinnac/osaka/python_1.py
```

Note that by right this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python buffers writes to `stdout` and `stderr`, and flushes the buffer on exit. You need to force a flush to see your message from python earlier:

```
import sys
print "This is " + sys.argv[0]
sys.stdout.flush()
```