# How to append a timestamp to each line as it comes out of grep?

Tags: php, logging, grep, timestamp

I have an infinite stream of data coming out of a logger, which I am piping to grep. I would like to save the output of the grep to a file, but also include a timestamp at the beginning of each line (the time at which the line appeared). Is there  an easy way to accomplish this? Assume I cannot change the output of the logger process.

Comment: Duplicate question, with aswers:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26728/52959

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a Unix utility to prepend timestamps to stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-stdin)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can append a **static timestamp** using `sed` and `date`:

```
... | sed "s/^/$(date) /" >> output.txt
```

---

Alternatively, if you require a **realtime timestamp**, use `gawk`'s [strftime function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html):

```
... | gawk '{ print strftime(), $0 }'
```

You can define your favourite formatting:

```
... | gawk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0 }'
```

And if buffering is a problem, don't forget to [flush](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html) each line:

```
... | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush() }'
```

Alternatively, use `unbuffer`:

```
unbuffer ... | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0 }'
```

---

If you don't have `gawk`, you have a couple of **other options**:

(a) Install `ts` (from [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)):

```
... | ts '%F %T'
```

(b) Use `perl`:

```
... | perl -pe 's/^/localtime . " "/e'
```

or with formatting:

```
... | perl -MPOSIX -pe 's/^/strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime) . " "/e'
```

Don't forget that you can use `gmtime` instead of `localtime` if you need GMT formatted to your locale.

(c) [Ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: it always output the initial time, time didn't change.

Comment: @ManjulaWeerasinge: Please see the changes. Thanks for the vote.