# Perl script log to file, output lag

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I have a Perlscript which does some logfile parsing and sometimes executes a bash command:

```
$messagePath = `ls -t -d -1 $dir | head -n 5 | xargs grep -l "$messageSearchString"\`;
```

I start my perl script like this `./perlscript.pl > logfile.log`.

Now I do a tail on the logfile to watch the progress, but the output gets stuck every time at the line I described above. 
The output will stop there for some seconds and then continue. ???

To profile the problem I wrapped it like this:

```
print `date`;
$messagePath = `ls -t -d -1 $dir | head -n 5 | xargs grep -l "$messageSearchString"`;
print `date`;
```

The output shows that the command does not consume a lot of time:

```
So 6. Okt 22:35:04 CEST 2013
So 6. Okt 22:35:04 CEST 2013
```

If I run the script without redirecting the output to a file there is no LAG.

Any idea why?

Comment: 1) programming questions are off topic here, you can post them on [su] or, in the case of common *nix scripting languages like Perl, on [unix.se] 2) [Never parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried to duplicate your behaviour, but it might be a stdout buffering problem. Try with:

```
$| = 1;
$messagePath = `ls -t -d -1 $dir | head -n 5 | xargs grep -l "$messageSearchString"`;
```

## Update

I *have* tried to duplicate the behaviour you observe: I've had to make some assumptions but I believe my suspicion was correct. Here I'm piping, but it's the same as redirecting to a file and tailing that file:

```
./test.pl |  awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; }'
```

Without `$| = 1`, output is buffered and aggregated:

```
2013-10-06 23:08:27 Saluton, mondo: /home/lserni/test.sh
2013-10-06 23:08:27
2013-10-06 23:08:27 Waiting 10s...
2013-10-06 23:08:27 Saluton denove!
```

With the modification, each line is printed as it is generated:

```
2013-10-06 23:09:09 Saluton, mondo: /home/lserni/test.sh
2013-10-06 23:09:09
2013-10-06 23:09:09 Waiting 10s...
2013-10-06 23:09:19 Saluton denove!
```

I expect that your script is doing *something* that takes some seconds, and which is *not* generating that `messagePath`; and the output will be delayed until Perl has a sizeable chunk of data to send along, giving the impression that it's that line that's stalling.

*I forgot: the timing pipe comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-lines-of-text)*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was indeed a buffering problem.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like yours, I've had some success using the [unbuffer](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unbuffer1.html) command. It runs a command in an environment that looks to the command like it's outputting to a tty so it doesn't buffer its output. I don't know how to apply it exactly in your case, so if you want to try it, you will have to experiment a little.