# how to add a timestamp along with the error log for a script from crontab

Tags: linux, cron

I have a crontab running like:

```
*/15 * * * 4,5   /apps/ins/sid/compare_stats 2>> /apps/ins/sid/compare_stats.err
```

Everything working as expected. the only thing is I want my error logs to generate in the `compare_stats.err` file like this:

```
Jul 3 14:45:04 <error text>
```

which means I just want to add a `date` along with this. Is there any way to do it by modifying the crontab entry ( without really making any change in my script) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Unix utility to prepend timestamps to lines of text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-lines-of-text)

Comment: @slhsen I already tried something like this :

`*/15 * * * 4,5   /apps/ins/sid/compare_stats|/usr/bin/awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }' 2>> /apps/ins/sid/compare_stats.err` doesn't really work for me

Comment: I also don't have any of the default utilities as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-lines-of-text as I'm using a `customized` `RHEL 5.10`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ts` command which is part of the `moreutils` package. E.g.:

```
*/15 * * * 4,5   /apps/ins/sid/compare_stats | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' 2>> /apps/ins/sid/compare_stats.err
```

This will prepend the timestamp to every line of the output and save it into your log.