# How to append a time to command output?

Tags: linux, bash

I use xev to debug x11 events for a window. I can filter events using grep, for example: `xev -id windowid | grep FocusIn`. I want to append time to each output from the above command `(date +"%T.%N")` . I need to know when each event occured. Is it possible ? How to achieve that ?

**Edit1**

Following command works:

```
xev -id windowid | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'
```

but with grep there is no output:

```
xev -id windowid | grep FocusIn | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'
```

When I use grep and ts there is also no output:

```
xev -id windowid | grep FocusIn | ts
```

How to fix that ?

Comment: Are you sure that what you are grep'ping is actually appearing in its input?

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the output through the `ts` command, if it is available on your system and if prepending (instead of appending) the timestamp is fine for you.

Otherwise you can use `awk` as described here:

[Is there a Unix utility to prepend timestamps to stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-lines-of-text)