# Is there a Unix utility to prepend to stdin the time in milliseconds since the start of the command?

Tags: shell, unix

I ended up writing a quick little script for this in NodeJS, but I was wondering if there was a utility you could feed text into which would prepend each line with some text -- in my specific case, the time elapsed in milliseconds since the start of the programm. Ideally, the use would be something like:

```
longrunningprocess | prepend-timestamp
```

This could help do some fast debugging.

This question looks very similar to [Is there a Unix utility to prepend timestamps to stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-lines-of-text), but is not the same, I would like to prepend milliseconds since the start of the program, not the current timestamp.

Here is my version using NodeJS:

```
#!/bin/env node

var moment = require("moment");
process.stdin.resume()

var fullData = "";
var t = +new Date();

process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
  fullData += data;
  splitted = fullData.split("\n");
  splitted.forEach(function (part) {
    if (part === "" ) {
      return process.stdout.write("\n");
    }
    process.stdout.write( (+new Date() - t) + " " + part +  "\n");
  })
  fullData = splitted[splitted.length-1];
});

process.stdout.on('error', function(err) {
  if (err.code === 'EPIPE') return process.exit()
    process.emit('error', err)
});
```

Bonus points if the ANSI escapes are kept (eg to see the colors of the initial command),

It would be even better if the precision (eg number of decimals) could be configurable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux, the [`ts` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ts.1.html) fits the bill.

If you only need resolution to the second, you can just use bash:

```
start=$SECONDS
longrunningprocess | while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$((SECONDS - start)): $line"
done
```

The `$SECONDS` variable gives you the number of seconds since the shell started. It's very useful for this kind of duration calculation.

---

OK, I didn't fully understand all your requirements. Here's a version with Perl:

```
atime () { 
    local precision="${1:-5}"
    perl -MTime::HiRes=time -sne '
        BEGIN {$start = time} 
        printf "%.${prec}f %s", (time - $start), $_
    ' -- -prec="$precision"
}

longrunningprocess | atime 3
```

Demo:

```
$ { echo foo; sleep 1; echo bar; } | atime
0.00010 foo
0.98499 bar
$ { echo foo; sleep 1; echo bar; } | atime 3
0.000 foo
0.980 bar
```

Comment: `ts '%.s'` works quite well, but do you have an idea of how I could have the time relative to the start of the command rather than relative to the 1970-01-01 ? (Eg have the first line be 0, and consecutive lines 0.001, ...)

Comment: The command you posted doesn't give relative time (for ts), and not the milliseconds precision (for your bash solution)

Comment: Hmm, I just realized that `ts` is actually implemented as a perl script using Time::HiRes. I've just reinvented it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using both ts to print the current timestamp with milliseconds  and awk to calculate the difference:

```
#!/bin/sh
# atime <precision>

precision=${1:-"5"}
ts '%.s' |
awk -v p="$precision" 'NR == 1 {st = $1} {diff = $1 - st; sub(/^[[:digit:].]+ /,""); printf "%."p"f %s\n", diff, $0}'
```

For example

```
{  echo "foo" ; sleep 1 ; echo "bar" ; } | atime
```

Prints :

```
0.00000 foo
0.97711 bar
```

Comment: You don't need to use line continuations inside a single quoted string.

Comment: You may want to run a few accuracy tests. There is something overtly suspicious about `foo` and `bar` being separated by less than the `1 second` time slept.

Comment: @david, I get the same results.

Comment: I guess the 3ms delay comes from the fact that ts needs some time to startup.

Comment: Yes, it's not much, but if you need extreme accuracy, that is something you need to consider. If you just need a ballpark, then I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Yes, get a better showing with `{ echo foo; sleep 1; echo bar; sleep 1; echo baz; } | atime`

Comment: @edi9999, you can tighten up your awk quite a bit: (without newlines due to comment) `awk -v p="$precision" 'NR == 1 {st = $1} {diff = $1 - st; sub(/^[[:digit:].]+ /,""); printf "%."p"f %s\n", diff, $0}'`