# Inserting timestamps into stream in bash

Tags: bash, sed, timestamp

I have a stream of data I'm receiving on stdin and I would like to add timestamps onto the steam. Ideally every line I would like to replace the new line with the current epoch seconds

`... | sed "s/$/$(date +' %s')"/` won't work because it will just evaluate the date command once on command.

What can I do?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56189/appending-timestamp-stamp-along-with-log-file-lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depending on your OS, you could

1. use the [`ts`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ts.1.html) command: 
   this will put the timestamp at the *beginning* of the line

   ```
   ... | ts '%s'
   ```
2. use GNU awk

   ```
   ... | gawk '{print $0, systime()}'
   ```
3. or perl

   ```
   ... | perl -lpe '$_ .= " ".time'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I can't flag this as a duplicate or comment on it, but take a look at the same question asked here before: [Is there a Unix utility to prepend timestamps to stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-stdin)

From there, you can use either `ts` (which has to be installed via `apt-get install moreutils`) or `awk`.