# How can I show the steps time of wget?

Tags: wget

How can I show the steps time of wget?

[image]

you see my snapshot, in my PC, I use `wget` to download a http page.

you see there have DNS resolve, TCP connection, and the HTTP response.

how can I show every step time?

so I can know every step using time:

(DNS resolve   3ms)
(TCP connection   5ms)
(HTTP response 10ms)

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way of getting this from `wget`. But you can use the answer to this question to get something close of what you want :
[Is there a Unix utility to prepend timestamps to stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-stdin)

You have to be aware that output of `wget` is not going to `stdout` but to errors' ouput and you have to redirect it : with `2>&1`

So it gives something like this :

```
------$ wget http://www.google.com 2>&1 | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'
2020-08-04 22:55:46 --2020-08-04 22:55:46--  http://www.google.com/
2020-08-04 22:55:46 Résolution de www.google.com (www.google.com)… 2a00:1450:4007:80c::2004, 216.58.201.228
2020-08-04 22:55:46 Connexion à www.google.com (www.google.com)|2a00:1450:4007:80c::2004|:80… connecté.
2020-08-04 22:55:46 requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse… 200 OK
2020-08-04 22:55:46 Taille : non indiqué [text/html]
2020-08-04 22:55:46 Enregistre : «index.html.10»
2020-08-04 22:55:46 
2020-08-04 22:55:46      0K .......... .                                           5,74M=0,002s
2020-08-04 22:55:46 
2020-08-04 22:55:46 2020-08-04 22:55:46 (5,74 MB/s) - «index.html.10» enregistré [11886]
2020-08-04 22:55:46
```